# mapping data from firestore snapshot doc Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

i'm beginner in Fletter and i want to learn and improve my skill in, so i follow a tutorial on how to make a todo app.

i have an error in getting data from firestore and get the values to three parameters. i made a search but i didn't find any solution of this issue. i hope someone help me to correct the code and explain to me the issue to avoid it in the next time.

thanks for your time.

my code :

```
List<Todo> todoFromFirestore(QuerySnapshot snapshot) {
return snapshot.docs.map((e) {
  return Todo(
    isComplet: e.data()["isComplet"],
    title: e.data()["title"],
    uid: e.id,
  );
}).toList();
}
```

Ps: the tutorial uploaded since 8 months ago and i use the latest flutter version

Comment: Please show the whole error that you got

Comment: the error : `The method '[]' can't be unconditionally invoked because the receiver can be 'null'.
Try making the call conditional (using '?.') or adding a null check to the target`